# VBA Retrieve the name of the user associated with logged username

Tags: vba

I want to get the full name of the user (logged in already) in VBA. This code I found online would do getting the username:

```
UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
```

but I want the user's real name. I found some hint about NetUserGetInfo but not sure what to think or do. Any hints will be appreciated
Regards,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the API answer complex as well in addition to needing recoding from a form to module

The function below comes courtesy of Rob Sampson from this  [Experts-Exchange post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/VB_Script/Q_23880233.html). It is a flexible function, see code comments for details. Please note it was a vbscript so the variables are not dimensioned

```
Sub Test()
    strUser = InputBox("Please enter a username:")
    struserdn = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", strUser, "displayName")
    If Len(struserdn) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox struserdn
    Else
        MsgBox "No record of " & strUser
    End If
End Sub

Function Get_LDAP_User_Properties(strObjectType, strSearchField, strObjectToGet, strCommaDelimProps)

' This is a custom function that connects to the Active Directory, and returns the specific
' Active Directory attribute value, of a specific Object.
' strObjectType: usually "User" or "Computer"
' strSearchField: the field by which to seach the AD by. This acts like an SQL Query's WHERE clause.
'             It filters the results by the value of strObjectToGet
' strObjectToGet: the value by which the results are filtered by, according the strSearchField.
'             For example, if you are searching based on the user account name, strSearchField
'             would be "samAccountName", and strObjectToGet would be that speicific account name,
'             such as "jsmith".  This equates to "WHERE 'samAccountName' = 'jsmith'"
' strCommaDelimProps: the field from the object to actually return.  For example, if you wanted
'             the home folder path, as defined by the AD, for a specific user, this would be
'             "homeDirectory".  If you want to return the ADsPath so that you can bind to that
'             user and get your own parameters from them, then use "ADsPath" as a return string,
'             then bind to the user: Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strReturnADsPath)

' Now we're checking if the user account passed may have a domain already specified,
' in which case we connect to that domain in AD, instead of the default one.
    If InStr(strObjectToGet, "\") > 0 Then
        arrGroupBits = Split(strObjectToGet, "\")
        strDC = arrGroupBits(0)
        strDNSDomain = strDC & "/" & "DC=" & Replace(Mid(strDC, InStr(strDC, ".") + 1), ".", ",DC=")
        strObjectToGet = arrGroupBits(1)
    Else
        ' Otherwise we just connect to the default domain
        Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
        strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    End If

    strBase = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & ">"
    ' Setup ADO objects.
    Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set ADOConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    ADOConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    ADOConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    adoCommand.ActiveConnection = ADOConnection


    ' Filter on user objects.
    'strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
    strFilter = "(&(objectClass=" & strObjectType & ")(" & strSearchField & "=" & strObjectToGet & "))"

    ' Comma delimited list of attribute values to retrieve.
    strAttributes = strCommaDelimProps
    arrProperties = Split(strCommaDelimProps, ",")

    ' Construct the LDAP syntax query.
    strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
    adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
    ' Define the maximum records to return
    adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

    ' Run the query.
    Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
    ' Enumerate the resulting recordset.
    strReturnVal = ""
    Do Until adoRecordset.EOF
        ' Retrieve values and display.
        For intCount = LBound(arrProperties) To UBound(arrProperties)
            If strReturnVal = "" Then
                strReturnVal = adoRecordset.Fields(intCount).Value
            Else
                strReturnVal = strReturnVal & vbCrLf & adoRecordset.Fields(intCount).Value
            End If
        Next
        ' Move to the next record in the recordset.
        adoRecordset.MoveNext
    Loop

    ' Clean up.
    adoRecordset.Close
    ADOConnection.Close
    Get_LDAP_User_Properties = strReturnVal

End Function
```

Answer (score 16):

Even if this thread is rather old, other users might be still googling around (like me).
I found an excellent short solution that worked for me out-of-the-box (thanks to [Mr.Excel.com](http://www.mrexcel.com)). 
I changed it because I needed it to return a string with the user's full name.
The original post is [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/347229-visual-basic-applications-how-do-i-get-full-user-name-not-login-id.html).

EDIT:
Well, I fixed a mistake, "End Sub" instead of "End Function" and added a variable declaration statement, just in case. I tested it in Excel 2010 and 2013 versions. Worked fine on my home pc too (no domain, just in a workgroup).

```
' This function returns the full name of the currently logged-in user
Function GetUserFullName() as String
    Dim WSHnet, UserName, UserDomain, objUser
    Set WSHnet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    UserName = WSHnet.UserName
    UserDomain = WSHnet.UserDomain
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & UserDomain & "/" & UserName & ",user")
    GetUserFullName = objUser.FullName
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, people are still googling around for this, lol.  In Excel 2016, this causes Excel to freeze and gives back either an empty string or a space.  Are there any prerequisite software packages to make this work?  The other examples use WMI, which requires certain packages to be installed.

Comment: And still in 2020 people are searching for this kind of functionality! It works like a charm in Word 2016 VBA. Great and simple code sample! No need for connecting with de AD and it gives me de user domain indeed. Thanks!

Comment: This works in 2023 as well. Excel 365.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. It might need some adjustments - I get several items returned and only one has `.Flags > 0`

```
Function GetUserFullName() As String
    Dim objWin32NLP As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Win32_NetworkLoginProfile class  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394221%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    Set objWin32NLP = GetObject("WinMgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "WMI is not installed", vbExclamation, "Windows Management Instrumentation"
      Exit Function
    End If
    For Each objItem In objWin32NLP
       If objItem.Flags > 0 Then GetUserFullName = objItem.FullName
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20111010032826/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151774):

> #### How To Call NetUserGetInfo from Visual Basic
>
> (From Microsoft Knowledge Base, article ID 151774)
>
> The NetUserGetInfo function is a Unicode-only Windows NT API. The last parameter of this function is a pointer to a pointer to a structure whose members contain DWORD data and pointers to Unicode strings. In order to call this function correctly from a Visual Basic application, you need to de-reference the pointer returned by the function and then you need to convert the Visual Basic string to a Unicode string and vice versa. This article illustrates these techniques in an example that calls NetUserGetInfo to retrieve a USER_INFO_3 structure from a Visual Basic application.
>
> The example below uses the Win32 RtlMoveMemory function to de-reference the pointer returned by the NetUserGetInfo call.
>
> **Step-by-Step Example**
>
> 1. Start Visual Basic. If Visual Basic is already running, from the File menu, choose New Project. `Form1` is created by default.
> 2. Add a Command button, `Command1`, to `Form1`.
> 3. Add the following code to the General Declarations section of `Form1`:
>
> ```
> ' definitions not specifically declared in the article:
>
> ' the servername and username params can also be declared as Longs,
> ' and passed Unicode memory addresses with the StrPtr function.
> Private Declare Function NetUserGetInfo Lib "netapi32" _
>                               (ByVal servername As String, _
>                               ByVal username As String, _
>                               ByVal level As Long, _
>                               bufptr As Long) As Long
>
> Const NERR_Success = 0
>
> Private Declare Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias _
>       "RtlMoveMemory" (pDest As Any, pSource As Any, ByVal dwLength As Long)
>
> Private Declare Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" (lpString As Any) As Long
>
> ' Converts a Unicode string to an ANSI string
> ' Specify -1 for cchWideChar and 0 for cchMultiByte to return string length.
> Private Declare Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "kernel32" _
>                            (ByVal codepage As Long, _
>                            ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
>                            lpWideCharStr As Any, _
>                            ByVal cchWideChar As Long, _
>                            lpMultiByteStr As Any, _
>                            ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, _
>                            ByVal lpDefaultChar As String, _
>                            ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As Long) As Long
>
>
> Private Declare Function NetApiBufferFree Lib "netapi32" _
>          (ByVal Buffer As Long) As Long
>
> ' CodePage
> Const CP_ACP = 0        ' ANSI code page
>
> Private Type USER_INFO_3
>    usri3_name As Long              'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_password As Long          'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_password_age As Long      'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_priv As Long              'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_home_dir As Long          'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_comment As Long           'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_flags As Long             'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_script_path As Long       'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_auth_flags As Long        'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_full_name As Long         'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_usr_comment As Long       'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_parms As Long             'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_workstations As Long      'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_last_logon As Long        'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_last_logoff As Long       'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_acct_expires As Long      'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_max_storage As Long       'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_units_per_week As Long    'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_logon_hours As Long       'PBYTE in SDK
>    usri3_bad_pw_count As Long      'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_num_logons As Long        'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_logon_server As Long      'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_country_code As Long      'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_code_page As Long         'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_user_id As Long           'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_primary_group_id As Long  'DWORD in SDK
>    usri3_profile As Long           'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_home_dir_drive As Long    'LPWSTR in SDK
>    usri3_password_expired As Long  'DWORD in SDK
> End Type
>
>
> Private Sub Command1_Click()
> Dim lpBuf As Long
> Dim ui3 As USER_INFO_3
>
> ' Replace "Administrator" with a valid Windows NT user name.
> If (NetUserGetInfo("", StrConv("Administrator", vbUnicode), 3, _
> uf) = NERR_Success) Then
>    Call MoveMemory(ui3, ByVal lpBuf, Len(ui3))
>
>    MsgBox GetStrFromPtrW(ui3.usri3_name)
>
>    Call NetApiBufferFree(ByVal lpBuf)
> End If
>
> End Sub
>
> ' Returns an ANSI string from a pointer to a Unicode string.
>
> Public Function GetStrFromPtrW(lpszW As Long) As String
> Dim sRtn As String
>
> sRtn = String$(lstrlenW(ByVal lpszW) * 2, 0)   ' 2 bytes/char
>
> ' WideCharToMultiByte also returns Unicode string length
> '  sRtn = String$(WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ByVal lpszW, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 0)
>
> Call WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ByVal lpszW, -1, ByVal sRtn, Len(sRtn), 0, 0)
> GetStrFromPtrW = GetStrFromBufferA(sRtn)
>
> End Function
>
> ' Returns the string before first null char encountered (if any) from an ANSI string.
>
> Public Function GetStrFromBufferA(sz As String) As String
> If InStr(sz, vbNullChar) Then
>    GetStrFromBufferA = Left$(sz, InStr(sz, vbNullChar) - 1)
> Else
>    ' If sz had no null char, the Left$ function
>    ' above would return a zero length string ("").
>    GetStrFromBufferA = sz
> End If
> End Function
> ```

I would recommend re-factoring this into a module rather than embedding it in the form itself. I've used this successfully in Access in the past.

Comment: will this work to get the name of the user? I find it almost impossible to understand it without getting into details (which I will have to before coding)

Comment: Yep, make sure you pass in your AD domain server. You may need to mess about with permissions (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Your link is dead, which is why most SEs prefer to have you explain or copypasta the material from the linked site.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried so many things, but I suppose my organization does not allow me to query Active Directory (or I got the structure wrong). I could only get my account name (not full name) or the error *"No mapping between account names and security IDs was done"*

But after 2 weeks searching, I finally have a working solution that I wanted to share. My final hint can be found here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/application-username-equivalent-in-ms-access.1143798/page-2#post-5545265

> The value does appear in the registry i.e.
> "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\UserInfo\UserName"

Once I realized that, it was easy to access with VBA:

```
UserName = CreateObject("wscript.shell").RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\UserInfo\UserName")
```

I assume (did not test though) that this is what `Application.Username` from Excel uses as well. Might not be perfect, but I finally have a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just  `UserName = Application.UserName`
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.username)

Comment: This answer provides the name that the user entered into whichever Office application that the VBA code is running within. The question is about the real name of the user associated with their Windows login (assuming a Windows device).