# How can I display my windows user name in excel spread sheet using macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to display the windows user name in a excel cell.

How can I do this?

Comment: "...ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical"... really? Seems pretty obvious that he wants to display the windows username in a cell - this is clear in the first and last sentence of the question.

Comment: I don't think this question could be any more clear or concise as to what the asker wants.  And given the brevity of a full and complete answer, it just seems that there are some people/mods on this SE that have an ax to grind.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
Range("A1").value = Environ("Username")
```

This is better than `Application.Username`, which doesn't always supply the Windows username. Thanks to [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240154/kyle) for pointing this out.

- `Application Username` is the name of the User set in Excel > Tools > Options
- `Environ("Username")` is the name you registered for Windows; see Control Panel >System

Comment: wow amazing !! i have inserted the above code and it is working fine.thanku so much

Comment: Should be: `Range("A1").value = environ("username")` Application.Username isn't always the windows username

Comment: Agree Kyle, The other three options are superior to `Application.Username`. But I think the question was simply about using `Range("A1").value`

Comment: @Kyle, thanks for the info! I updated my answer. Brettdj, tbh I think so too, he found some code online that just displayed it in a messagebox. (don't think he did much research though)

Comment: @t.thielemans, the question was for the windows username, as the application username can be quite different (it is the user name the user gives on first opening the Excel application or whenever he/she changes it) the `application.username` per definition doesnt give the windows username and thus just is not the right answer...

Comment: @K_B, I edited my answer according to Kyles' suggestion, but as brettdj mentioned it was `Range("A1").value` he was more interested in.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7805856/321973) about the _full_ username instead of the login name

Comment: Environ("Username") gives the domain username back and Application.Username gives the local machine's username back according my experience. So, it depends on what you need.