# Retrieving username from computer

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get the actual username of the computer that my code is being run on.

I am currently using the code

```
user = Environ("USERNAME")
```

This gives me the actual log-in name (ex: jdoe) instead of John Doe.  I want to get John Doe. If you click the start button on Windows it shows the full name of the person logged in.  How can I use VBA to get that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i display my windows user name in excel spread sheet using macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412418/how-can-i-display-my-windows-user-name-in-excel-spread-sheet-using-macros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (in Excel VBA)

`Application.UserName`

Comment: `Application.Username` returns the full name of the user set in Excel, which isn't always the same as the windows full name ;). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412418/how-can-i-display-my-windows-user-name-in-excel-spread-sheet-using-macros) question, which answer will also direct you to a UDF to be used to retrieve windows full name.

Comment: @JvdV in my testing it worked fine and therefore I posted. It also has worked for the user. However, thank you for pointing this out.