# How can I call the the function in the VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, function, sap-gui

I have a SAP gui script that my colleagues has to run to downlead reports automatically in the shared folder.

```
Option Explicit
Public SapGuiAuto, WScript, msgcol
Public objGui  As GuiApplication
Public objConn As GuiConnection
Public session As GuiSession

Sub SAPDownloadAttachment()

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
Set session = objConn.Children(0)

Dim weeklyfrom As Date
Dim weeklyto As Date
Dim weeklylayout As String
Dim spectrafrom As Date
Dim spectrato As Date
Dim rddfrom As Date
Dim rddto As Date
Dim ordearreason As String
Dim spectralayout As String

User = find_user2()

weeklyfrom = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value
weeklyto = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value
weeklylayout = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E13").Value

spectrafrom = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I1").Value
spectrato = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("J1").Value
rddfrom = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I2").Value
rddto = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("J2").Value
ordearreason = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I13").Value
spectralayout = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I14").Value
```

Code is even bigger but I get the error at `User = find_user2()` which is the function to find the user ( this is the path were the report as to be downloaded and saved, since it will be used multiple users that's why I need to define the user which is not constant "C:\Users" & User & ".......)

Here is this function

```
Function find_user2() As String

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oSubFolder As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users")
User = ""

For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.subfolders
        If Dir("C:\Users\" & oSubFolder.Name & "\Name & Co\", vbDirectory) <> "" Then
            User = CStr(oSubFolder.Name)
            Exit For
        End If
        Next oSubFolder
        
find_user2 = CStr(User)

End Function
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `find_user2` supposed to return the logged-in user's login name?  There are better ways to do that.

Comment: yes exactly, that what I want

Comment: @TimWilliams Could you please show?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412418/how-can-i-display-my-windows-user-name-in-excel-spread-sheet-using-macros/13412522

Comment: but I dont have any value in cell, Do you have any idea how can I call my function in SAP gui script?

Comment: `User = Environ("Username")` should do it.

Comment: Dim UserName As String
UserName = Environ("username") like this?

Comment: Yes did you try that?

Comment: yes its working on my pc, I assume it will work on others too. Thanks. P.S it now has some problems on SAP script itself, asking some debugging not sure why

Comment: Sorry I can't help with that part.