# read windows username from smart card-enabled login on network computer

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, smartcard, hta

I am building an HTA application for my office.  We are using IE 9 on Windows 7.  I have found how to retrieve the user name via javascript and VBA, but I have an issue.  We log into our network with smart cards, and our user names are just numbers.  The numbers are basically employee numbers.  So when I get the user name from the local environment variable, it is just a number, which doesn't do me any good.  Even our user folder is the same as our number.  Interestingly, when you click the Start Menu, over in the right column at the top where your user name would normally appear, is our actual name plus our work center. This is exactly the info I need, but I don't know where it comes from.  Possibly a network script plugs this info in? Even if you click it, which normally takes you to your user folder, the address at the top is exactly the same as what was in the Start Menu.

I tried searching the window registry for my name and the best solution I could come up with (yet still far away from practical) is reading the user name key value in Microsoft Office registry.  Now, every computer should always have Office, but I don't like this approach one bit.

Our name is also stored on our Smart-Cards, but I imagine that is not something I can easily read from my application.

Anyone have another idea how I might be able to pull the information I am looking for?

Comment: I should add (or should I edit my post?) that I am just a user on said network.  I have no admin privileges.  I am simply writing an HTA application in JS and VBA (if needed) for our office needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query ActiveDirectory for user details. You got user login so retrieving other user properties is easy.

You can try to use script from this answer [VBA Retrieve the name of the user associated with logged username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805856/vba-retrieve-the-name-of-the-user-associated-with-logged-username) , but I suggest you to do this on server side. Just turn on Windows Authentication on IIS

Comment: I appreciate the help, I am trying to implement this into my code to see if it will work.  I'm quite fuzzy on network know-how so trying to adapt to my situation is taking a little time.

Answer (score 0):

To see if the info is available copy these commands into a command prompt. Do any of them have what you are after.

```
wmic path Win32_Account get /format:list

wmic path Win32_Group get /format:list

wmic path Win32_GroupInDomain get /format:list

wmic path Win32_GroupUser get /format:list

wmic path Win32_SystemAccount get /format:list

wmic path Win32_SystemUsers get /format:list

wmic path Win32_UserAccount get /format:list
```

Comment: I probably should have added a little more info.  I am just a user and have no admin privileges.  I cannot drop to command prompt, but I did load wmic from the start menu.  I got a prompt and typed 'path Win32_Account get /format:list'... and it did nothing.  It just sat there with the cursor blinking at me.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your username that you want, search the registry for it. If your name is fred then type in Run dialog (Winkey + R)

```
reg query hkcu /f "fred" /s>"%userprofile%\desktop\reg.txt"
```

It put results into a txt file on your desktop.

What happens if you type cmd /k in Start Run.

Comment: Sorry it's taking me so long to respond, I don't have access to reply at work.

cmd /k in Start Run gives me the same error I mentioned before, which that Command Prompt has been disabled by Administration.

Searching the registry via query did not post anything to my desktop.