# Validating user name with global user list in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a an excel to track production in my organization. I have a user list with user names (windows). I wanted to validate the user name with the global list of the company whenever some adds a new user name to the list.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information Manu. Is the Windows username list in an excel sheet? Can you access the 'global list of the company' from within Excel? How are you doing this? Is it a query or vba?

Comment: I wanted to compare the user name with the windows network user names. For example if I'm trying to give a particular user access to a cell/range, we will get a windows permission dialogue box in which I can check add new user from network user list. I want the check name feature in the dialogue box

Comment: I may be misinterpreting your requirement but it sounds to me as though you want a userform that presents all of the Windows usernames/details and you want to be able to select one which then gets added to a list?

Comment: If some one adds a user name in a list (in excel cell) i just wanted to validate whether it is a valid network user or not

Comment: Understood. Check out the following which could be modified to instead of returning the name, be used to check if the login exists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805856/vba-retrieve-the-name-of-the-user-associated-with-logged-username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a simple function for the same

```
Function GetUserFullName(userName) As String
    Set WSHnet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    UserDomain = WSHnet.UserDomain
    On Error GoTo Err_open_esy
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & UserDomain & "/" & userName & ",user")
Exit_open_esy:
    GetUserFullName = objUser.FullName
Exit Function

Err_open_esy:
    GetUserFullName = "Error"
End Function
```

can use as

```
GetUserFullName("abc")
```