# Using cell vlaue with WScript.Network to pull domain data

Tags: excel, vba

I am building something that requires details associated with a user in the company to be pre-populated when the username is submitted.

I am working with 'CreateObject("WScript.Network")'. I essentially want to put user A's login name in to cell A1, then using that number return the details in the company network relating to that username.

Can it be done?

Comment: Yes probably...Try querying `Envrion` to see what you can get

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831157/3219613 if you want to read the LDAP User Properties. Note that the function provided there can read more than only the users `displayName` if you feed it with the correct parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting AD Details based on username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110232/getting-ad-details-based-on-username).

Comment: So I found wscript essentially pulls the same data as environ. However looked in to LDAP after sifting through stack and have managed to get this to work after creating a function that works with a cells value as the variable! Thanks everyone for your comments :)